# preg_match Delimiter error

Tags: php, preg-match, delimiter

Good day,
I have read about 25 different articles talking about adding a "/" or a "~" etc.., for a delimiter but to no avail with this line of code. Everything I have tried it still gives me a delimiter error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time. Below is the original code which caused all of my research.

```
$allowedHosts = array();

// self
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if( preg_match('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', $host) ) {
    $allowedHosts[] = $host;
} else {
    $allowedHosts[] = '*.' . $host;
    $allowedHosts[] = $host;
}
```

Comment: What is a "delimiter error"?  Exactly what error message did you get?

Answer (score 4):

You need delimiters around the regular expression:

```
if( preg_match('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $host) ) {
```

In this case I used `/` which is pretty standard. But you could use other symbols:

```
if( preg_match('@\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+@', $host) ) {
```

A [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

I assume from looking at your regex you are trying to match an IP address, you could try this instead:

```
$IP = "198.168.1.78";
if (preg_match('/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/',$IP)) {
    echo "Your IP address is ok.";
} else {
    echo "Wrong IP address.";
}
```

Comment: For reference, [Delimiters](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). "_A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character._"

Comment: I tried using delimiters as you described, however, I still receive the following error.2011-12-20T04:33:11+00:00 WARN (4): [2] preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' (/var/www/html/application/modules/Core/controllers/CrossDomainController.php)

Comment: You should escape the dot in the first group.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to validate an IP address.

PHP has a built-in for that...

```
$validIp = filter_var($host, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

Comment: Where would I apply this in the php? I am a noob at this sort of thing.

Comment: @MarkEllis: Swap the body of the condition with the above minus the assignment.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Now to tackle a separate problem that arises since this is now correct. ha. Thank you for your help!